# What is "wua" mode when opening a file in python?

Tags: python, file

I have recently been going through some of our windows python 2.4 code and come across this:

```
self.logfile = open(self.logfile_name, "wua")
```

I know what `w`, `u` and `a` do on their own, but what happens when you combine them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `a` is superfluous. `wua` is the same as `wu` since `w` comes first and will thus truncate the file. If you would reverse the order, that is, `auw`, that would be the same as `au`. Visualized:

```
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> f.read()
'Initial contents\n'
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'wua')
>>> print >> f, 'writing'
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> f.read()
'writing\n'
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'auw')
>>> print >> f, 'appending'
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> f.read()
'writing\nappending\n'
>>> f.close()
```

(Reminder: both `a` and `w` [open the file for writing](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#open), but the former appends while the other truncates.)

Answer (score 3):

I did not notice that you knew what the modifiers did. Combined they will do the following:

A and W together is superfluous since both will open for writing. When using W, the file will be overwritten. When using A, all new text is appended after the existing content.

U means  "open file XXX for input as a text file with universal newline interpretation".

- W is for Write
- A is for Append
- U will
  convert the file to use the defined
  newline character.

More here:
http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1969

Answer (score 2):

Underneath the hood Python 2.4 passes the the builtin `open`'s arguments on to the operating system's `fopen` function. Python does do some mangling of the mode string under certain conditions.

```
if (strcmp(mode, "U") == 0 || strcmp(mode, "rU") == 0)
    mode = "rb";
```

So if you pass an upper case `U` or `rU` it will open the file for binary reading. Looking at the GNU libc source and according to the MSDN page describing the windows implementation of `fopen` the '`u`' option is ignored.

Having more than one mode designator ('`r`', '`w`' and '`a`') in the mode string has no effect. This can be seen by looking at the GNU libc implementation of mode string parsing:

```
switch (*mode)
{
case 'r':
  omode = O_RDONLY;
  break;
case 'w':
  omode = O_WRONLY;
  oflags = O_CREAT|O_TRUNC;
  break;
case 'a':
  omode = O_WRONLY;
  oflags = O_CREAT|O_APPEND;
  break;
default:
  __set_errno (EINVAL);
  return NULL;
}
```

The first character of the mode string is searched for one of '`r`', '`w`' or '`a`', if it's not one of these characters an error is raised.

Therefore when a file is opened as "`wua`" it will be opened for writing only, created if it doesn't exist and truncated. '`u`' and '`a`' will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how things are implemented internally!